# Unexpected SyntaxError: Cannot use import

Tags: node.js

This file is from a `type-graphql` tutorial by Ben Awad. I have read multiple questions about this, however, this error was truly strange for the following reasons:

- Running `nodemon --exec ts-node-transpile-only ./src/index.ts` works
- The error comes *only* from one file, User.ts. Note that I also use `import {...} from "typeorm", import {...} from "type-graphql"` elsewhere.
- Running `tsc -w` followed by `nodemon --exec node ./dist/index.js` does not, and generates the following error.

```
import { BaseEntity, Column, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from "typeorm";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1001:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at /home/sunjc826/Desktop/languages/Javascript/graphql/type-graphql-ben-awad/node_modules/typeorm/util/DirectoryExportedClassesLoader.js:42:39
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Object.importClassesFromDirectories (/home/sunjc826/Desktop/languages/Javascript/graphql/type-graphql-ben-awad/node_modules/typeorm/util/DirectoryExportedClassesLoader.js:42:10)
```

The affected file:

```
import { BaseEntity, Column, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from "typeorm";
import { Field, ObjectType, ID, Root } from "type-graphql";

@ObjectType()
@Entity()
export class User extends BaseEntity {
  @Field(() => ID)
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Field()
  @Column()
  firstName: string;

  @Field()
  @Column()
  lastName: string;

  @Field()
  @Column("text", { unique: true })
  email: string;

  @Field()
  name(@Root() parent: User): string {
    return `${parent.firstName} ${parent.lastName}`;
  }

  @Column()
  password: string;
}
```

Similar imports in entry point `index.ts` that does not generate complaints:

```
import { buildSchema } from "type-graphql";
import { createConnection } from "typeorm";
```

My tsconfig:

```
"target": "es6",
"module": "commonjs",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the error. In ormconfig.json, I had setup entities like this:

```
"entities": ["src/entity/*.*"]
```

but since I'm running the program with node (instead of ts-node) in the dist folder, it should actually be

```
"entities": ["dist/entity/*.*"]
```